# Cannot assign value of Bool type to type String Database Representation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to add a non string type of data to the DatabaseRepresentation. I have tried AnyObject, but doesn't conform to hashable protocol.

lastMessageRead is of Bool type or do I simply store this as a String?

```
extension Channel: DatabaseRepresentation {

    var representation: [String : Any] {
        var rep = ["ownerName": ownerName]
        rep["ownerId"] = ownerId
        rep["participantName"] = participantName
        rep["participantId"] = participantId
        rep["lastMessage"] = lastMessage
        rep["lastMessageId"] = lastMessageId

        if let lastMessageRead = lastMessageRead {
            rep["lastMessageRead"] = lastMessageRead **Cannot assign Bool to String
        }

        if let id = id {
            rep["id"] = id
        }
        return rep
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague because there's no indication what `lastMessageRead` is and that's where the problem is. The answer being provided (so far) are a workaround and are not addressing the actual issue. i.e. why go through the effort of casting a bool to a string when you really want a bool so you can test for true and false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
var representation: [String : String]

rep["yourData"] = "\(your data)"
```

For date :

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    formatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let text = formatter.string(from: yourDateValue)
    rep["yourDate"] = text
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks that has worked well for the Bool value. How would i go about a Date value?

Answer (score 0):

The type of `rep` is inferred as `[String:String]` dictionary.

Declare `rep` as `[String:Any]` then you can add `any` value without conversion.

Further it's not necessary to optional bind the two values. If they are `nil` nothing is added.

```
var representation: [String : Any] {
    var rep = [String : Any]()

    rep["ownerName"] = ownerName
    rep["ownerId"] = ownerId
    rep["participantName"] = participantName
    rep["participantId"] = participantId
    rep["lastMessage"] = lastMessage
    rep["lastMessageId"] = lastMessageId
    rep["lastMessageRead"] = lastMessageRead   
    rep["id"] = id
    return rep
}
```